# Exercise with residues of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

First, I have to study the singularities of $f(z)=(4z^2+1)\tanh (\pi z) $, and calculate the residues. This part should be correct, I found that   $f $ has simple poles in the points $\{z_n =\frac i 2+ni: n\in \mathbb Z,n\ne0,-1\}$, and removable singularities in $\frac i 2 $ and $-\frac i 2 $; the residue of the pole in a $z_n $ is equal to $\frac {4z_n^2+1} \pi$.

I'm in trouble with the second part: calculate $\int_{C_R (0)} f (z)dz$, for $R $ sufficiently large. My only idea was to sum the residues, so I tried with $$2\sum_1^\infty \frac { \Bigl(\frac i 2+in\Bigl)^2+1} \pi$$ since $f $ is symmetrical on the imaginary axis. However this series doesn't converge, so I think I must be wrong with something. Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you give a definition of $C_R(0)$?

Comment: Sorry, it is the set $\{z=Re^ {i\theta}\}$, with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]\subset \mathbb R $. ($R $ is real)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If as you say the residue at the pole $\;z_n=\cfrac{(2n+1) i}2\;$ is

$$\frac{4z_n^2+1}\pi=\frac1\pi\left(-(2n+1)^2+1\right)=\frac1\pi(-4n^2-4n)=-\frac{4n} \pi(n+1)$$

so for big $\;R\;$, we get a finite sum of residues

$$\frac4\pi\sum_{n=-k}^k(n^2+n)=\frac4\pi\left[2\sum_{n=1}^kn^2+0\right]=\frac8\pi\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}6=\frac4{3\pi}k(k+1)(2k+1)$$

Of course, you take out from the above the case for $\;n=-1\;$ and etc.

Comment: Thanks, so actually the integral doesn't converge to a finite value

Comment: Well, the integral's value for any $\;R\in\Bbb R\;$ exists and is written (almost) in the above. The integral doesn't converge for $\;R\to\infty\;$ ...